# Clicking hidden file input from within span causes RangeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the HTML:

```
<span class="btn btn-success js-uploader">
    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload
    <input type="file" multiple>
</span>
```

And the jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$('.js-uploader').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="file"]').click();
});
```

Basically, when a span with the class`.js-upload` is clicked, the file input should be clicked as well. But when I use `.find()` or `.js-uploader > input[type="file"]`, it causes a RangeError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

console message: `too much recursion`

when you click on the input it also bubles to span, but span click-handler also causes click on input

try to check if the event.target is input

```
$('.js-uploader').click(function(e){
     if ($(e.target).is('input[type="file"]')) return;
     $(this).find('input[type="file"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

heavy recursion .. check the fiddle here ..you will get to know http://jsfiddle.net/umBWV/1/